# R cannot be resolved to a variable during importing a project

Tags: android

****here i am pasting the problems details R cannot be resolved to a variable is common problem ,i checked my res folder ,done refreshing project ,cleaning project ,validate ** still error is not resolved help me guys...**

```
    [2012-12-14 02:12:38 - com.example.android.livecubes.cube2.CubeWallpaper2Settings] res\drawable\ic_launcher_wallpaper.png:0: error: Resource entry ic_launcher_wallpaper is already defined.
        [2012-12-14 02:12:38 - com.example.android.livecubes.cube2.CubeWallpaper2Settings] res\drawable\ic_launcher_wallpaper.html:0: Originally defined here.
        [2012-12-14 02:12:38 - com.example.android.livecubes.cube2.CubeWallpaper2Settings] res\xml\cube1.xml:0: error: Resource entry cube1 is already defined.
        [2012-12-14 02:12:38 - com.example.android.livecubes.cube2.CubeWallpaper2Settings] res\xml\cube1.html:0: Originally defined here.
        [2012-12-14 02:12:38 - com.example.android.livecubes.cube2.CubeWallpaper2Settings] res\xml\cube2.xml:0: error: Resource entry cube2 is already defined.
        [2012-12-14 02:12:38 - com.example.android.livecubes.cube2.CubeWallpaper2Settings] res\xml\cube2.html:0: Originally defined here.
        [2012-12-14 02:12:38 - com.example.android.livecubes.cube2.CubeWallpaper2Settings] res\xml\cube2_settings.xml:0: error: Resource entry cube2_settings is already defined.
        [2012-12-14 02:12:38 - com.example.android.livecubes.cube2.CubeWallpaper2Settings] res\xml\cube2_settings.html:0: Originally defined here.
        [2012-12-14 02:12:38 - com.example.android.livecubes.cube2.CubeWallpaper2Settings] F:\sample projects\Cube\res\values\index.html:112: error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag
        [2012-12-14 02:12:38 - com.example.android.livecubes.cube2.CubeWallpaper2Settings] F:\sample projects\Cube\res\values\shapes.html:112: error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag
        [2012-12-14 02:12:38 - com.example.android.livecubes.cube2.CubeWallpaper2Settings] F:\sample projects\Cube\res\values\strings.html:112: error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag
        [2012-12-14 02:12:38 - com.example.android.livecubes.cube2.CubeWallpaper2Settings] F:\sample projects\Cube\res\xml\cube1.html:112: error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag
        [2012-12-14 02:12:38 - com.example.android.livecubes.cube2.CubeWallpaper2Settings] F:\sample projects\Cube\res\xml\cube2.html:112: error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag
        [2012-12-14 02:12:38 - com.example.android.livecubes.cube2.CubeWallpaper2Settings] F:\sample projects\Cube\res\xml\cube2_settings.html:112: error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag
        [2012-12-14 02:12:38 - com.example.android.livecubes.cube2.CubeWallpaper2Settings] F:\sample projects\Cube\res\xml\index.html:112: error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag


/*
 * Copyright (C) 2009 Google Inc.
 * 
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 * use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
 * the License at
 * 
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */

package com.example.android.livecubes.cube2;

import com.example.android.livecubes.cube2.*;


import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class CubeWallpaper2Settings extends PreferenceActivity
    implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(
                CubeWallpaper2.SHARED_PREFS_NAME);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.cube2_settings);
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(
                this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(
                this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key) {
    }
}
```

Comment: problem@   addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.cube2_settings);

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have `res\drawable\ic_launcher_wallpaper.png` and `res\drawable\ic_launcher_wallpaper.html`. Not sure why you have HTML in your drawable folder, but rename or delete one of these two objects, then clean and rebuild your project.

Remember, resources are referred to by directory filename only (`drawable/a.png == drawable/a.html == drawable/a.jpg -> R.drawable.a`). They must have unique filenames.

Addendum: The same applies for other files. You have `cube1.xml` and `cube1.html` in your `xml` folder (and others listed in your log). These all have to be taken care of. Also seems these HTML files shouldn't even be there, as it's attempting to parse them as XML (which it probably won't manage).